# Polyfills for ES6 are not supplying uint8array.join for IE11

Tags: angular

I have a test application that is the default angular app built with the angular cli.  The only changes I've made are modifying polyfill and adding a call to Uint8array.join in the app.ts. 
Here is the app.component.ts ngOnInit function

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
  console.log("We got cookies");
  let bacon:Uint8Array=new Uint8Array([4,6]);
  console.log(bacon.join());
  }
}
```

And Here is the polyfill

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

I am getting 
'Object doesnt support property or method 'join'
where the Object is a Uint8array

Answer (score 0):

Typedarray `join()` function is not supported by IE11 ([TypedArray - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Browser_compatibility))

If you want to use this function in Angular you could Polyfill this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedarray